# Node.js callbacks passed into server.on()

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, arguments

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.on('request',function (req, res) {
    res.end('asdas');
});
```

How can I know which callback, with how many of arguments, should be passed?

I saw some tutorials, and in some cases callbacks have other amounts of args, like: `data`, `err`, `message`, `req`, `res`. Is it somewhere in Node.js docs and it depends on first argument passed into `.on()` function, or it depends on request type coming, or can I modify it in some my own way, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request).

The `request` event is emitted with two arguments, `request` an `response`. Your code is correct.